# Using starts_with in dplyr with a vector of partial column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to use dplyr to select certain columns that match to a string vector.

```
one <- seq(1:10)
two <- rnorm(10)
three <- runif(10, 1, 2)
four <- -10:-1

df <- data.frame(one, two, three, four)

vars <- c('on', 'thr')
```

I want to select only the columns in df whose titles start with'on' or 'thr':

```
dplyr::select_(df, starts_with(vars))
```

However, the above is not working.

Comment: `select(df, sapply(vars, starts_with))`. I think this is safe in most cases.

Comment: If you say _However, the above is not working._ what is the exact error message, please?

Comment: A simple, clunky, solution is `df %>% 
  select(starts_with(vars[1]), starts_with(vars[2]))`

Answer (score 6):

The various selection helper functions in dplyr are meant to take only a single character string for matching. You can get around this by combining your strings into one regular expression and using `matches`:

```
vars <- paste0("^(", paste(vars, collapse="|"), ")")
select(df, matches(vars))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Hong Ooi.  Your first statement is not true.  select has a helper function called one_of which takes a variable that is a vector of column names as an input.  I was hoping that I could use one_of along with starts_with to get what I wanted.  Anyways, your solution is nice, but I wish there's a way to do this in dplyr because it is easier to read and more elegant

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you know in advance, because you're coding it in, what column name matches you want, so you could use

```
select(starts_with("on"), starts_with("thr"))
```

Ah, I see Tony Ladson essentiall suggested this already. Depending on your exact use case, though, I don't see a need to get them from a vector.

Comment: I mean, if, for example, you want to interactively select column names a user might have selected in a shiny app, well you've got the full column names already.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `starts_with`:

```
df %>% 
  select(map(c('on', 'thr'), 
             starts_with, 
             vars = colnames(.)) %>% 
         unlist())
```

Basically, the idea is to apply the `starts_with` function to the vector of names by using `map`. 
But to get it to work, one must add the argument `vars`(the list of colnames), and then unlist the result of `map` to get the vector of positions.

This solution expands the one of Chrisss to the case where there are several matches for at least one entry.