# Selecting columns using ends_with helper and a vector of string names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame, in wide format, with each column representing one questionnaire **item** for one particular **version** of a questionnaire for a particular **time point** (repeated measures design).

My data would look something like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:5), t1_QOL_child_Q1 = c(5, 3, 6, 2, 7), t1_QOL_child_Q2 = c(5, 2, 3, 7, 1), t1_QOL_child_Q3 = c(7, 7, 6, 2, 5), t1_QOL_child_joy = c(9,9, 5, 3, 6), t1_QOL_teen_Q1 = c(5, 3, 6, 2, 7), t1_QOL_teen_Q2 = c(5, 2, 3, 7, 1), t1_QOL_teen_Q3 = c(7, 7, 6, 2, 5), t1_QOL_teen_joy = c(5, 7, 4, 7, 9), t1_QOL_adult_Q1 = c(5, 3, 6, 2, 7), t1_QOL_adult_Q2 = c(5, 2, 3, 7, 1), t1_QOL_adult_Q3 = c(7, 7, 6, 2, 5), t1_QOL_adult_joy = c(6, 5, 3, 3, 2), t2_QOL_child_Q1 = c(5, 3, 6, 2, 7), t2_QOL_child_Q2 = c(5, 2, 3, 7, 1), t2_QOL_child_Q3 = c(7, 7, 6, 2, 5), t2_QOL_child_joy = c(9,9, 5, 3, 6), t2_QOL_teen_Q1 = c(5, 3, 6, 2, 7), t2_QOL_teen_Q2 = c(5, 2, 3, 7, 1), t2_QOL_teen_Q3 = c(7, 7, 6, 2, 5), t2_QOL_teen_joy = c(5, 7, 4, 7, 9), t2_QOL_adult_Q1 = c(5, 3, 6, 2, 7), t2_QOL_adult_Q2 = c(5, 2, 3, 7, 1), t2_QOL_adult_Q3 = c(7, 7, 6, 2, 5), t2_QOL_adult_joy = c(6, 5, 3, 3, 2))
```

For example, column t1_QOL_child_Q1 would mean Question 1 (Q1) of the child version (child) of Quality of Life (QOL) questionnaire, with time point 1 (t1) data.

I want to select only subscales/columns whose suffix are labelled differently. In the sample data above, it would be the columns ending with "joy".

I have over 3000 columns and many more suffixes and it would be a pain to use the following:

```
select(df, ends_with("joy"), ends_with(<another suffix>), ends_with(<another suffix>))
```

I have thought of putting all the potential suffixes in a string vector, and use the vector as an input to the ends_with function, but ends_with could only take a single string instead of a vector of strings.

I have searched on Stackoverflow and found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125049/using-starts-with-in-dplyr-with-a-vector-of-partial-column-names) that could accommodate a small vector of strings, which is the following:

```
select(df, sapply(vector_of_strings, starts_with))
```

However, I have too many suffixes in my vector of strings and the following error message resulted from it: Error: `sapply(vector_of_strings, ends_with)` must resolve to integer column positions, not a list

Help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use a single `matches` with multiple patterns separated by `|` to match substrings at the end (`$`) of the string

```
df %>% 
    select(matches("(joy|Q2)$"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Just curious, how does match and $ work? Is match an exact match? If so, how does it match segments of a string?

Comment: @DTYK  It is regular expression.  The `$` is a metacharacter that signifies the end of the string.  The characters within the braces are matched and if they are separated by `|`, it implies either one of these match.  Suppose you need to match some columns that ends with 'Q2' and others start with 't2', that can be done as well `df %>% select(matches("^t2.*|joy$"))`